# Clear sensitive information from vdi

Tags: virtualbox, security, vdi

I'm able to obtain file names and their contents from vdi image using `grep` despite the files were deleted. Example output:

```
MICROS~3.DLLans0��1FR�b��?,|�R��?,|�R��?,|�R�� !Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll�H^@�x�x�1_��9�����yFILE0��m8��`HFR�b��FR�b��o�}�R��o�}�R�� �0xZ1FR�b��o�}�R��o�}�R��o�}�R��
```

When I mount the vdi image using `vdfuse`, `grep` can't find the same information. I've also tried wiping free space with `sdelete`, but without effect. How could I remove this information?

**Update**: Example output with email:

```
file.ext.LCK0xZ��0̮=T��0̮=T��0̮=T��0̮=T�� 
                                                                      FILEEX~1.LCK�X<NAMENAMENAME__aaaaaaaaa@aaaa.aaa.aa�����yGFILE0��l8��`H�y���y��v�R��v�R�� �0xZ1�y��O�t�R��O�t�R��O�t�R��
```

Comment: You want some sort of free space sanitation utility. Note that such is normally distinct from rewriting unused parts of the file system. This is unrelated to VirtualBox. Keep in mind that outright software recommendation questions are off-topic on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this seems to be the directory entry on a FAT filesystem, not the actual contents of the file. Just defragment the drive to get rid of deleted file entries from directories.

Comment: It's just an example. There are also deleted files with emails and names. And does `sdelete` do the same task?

Comment: `sdelete -z C:` promises to zero out unused space on the drive. Also promises to optimize virtual disk usage, but I have no idea how virtualbox decides what parts of disk can be made sparse. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443.aspx

Comment: I'm using it with `-c` flag. I've added an example with email to the question.